# If my parents are both non-US citizens living abroad, with no tax files, am I still classified as dependent for financial aid?

Tags: united-states, funding

I am a US citizen.
My parents are both non-US citizens living abroad, with no tax files.
They are not green-card holders.
I am 18 and do not have any household income to report because my household is not in the US.

I do not fit in any of the qualifying requirements to be ‘independent’ but I am also going to be alone in the US.
How exactly am I supposed to fill the file?
Am I still classified as dependent for financial aid?

Comment: For **regular tax purposes**, you are not a dependent, since no one is going to claim you on their US tax return.

Comment: They still want to know about your parents' income: https://studentaid.gov/help-center/answers/article/how-to-report-info-about-noncitizen-parents-on-fafsa

Comment: mkennedy, please don't answer questions in the comments. Instead, quote an excerpt from that link and paste it in your answer along with the link.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to call the federal student aid information center. They will give you the best possible answer to this situation. However, I will provide my opinion as a student though I may be wrong. Your parents have to have tax files. Otherwise signing for them as a dependent student will be challenging. Due to your situation you may be required to be labeled as an independent student, it may give you more financial aid if you explain your situation.